# Python max with same num of instances within a list

Tags: python, max, instance

For an assignment I was given I was to build a parser, which would extract relevant information from  json files, and present it in a user friendly report. With one of the features being to identify the malware based on the majority output. Which should work for n amount of json files.

I have successfully parsed all json files from a directory and have been able to extract all relevant information from the fields where it gives the malware it has detected, and have appended that information to a list for each json file. which can be seen here: [Lists created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ct8.jpg)

I need to iterate through each list and find the most frequent element/s within each list and append the most frequent element/s to a new list.

For my case **most common()** and **max()** functions wont work as there could be 5 elements in the list for json file 1 equal to the most common and 3 for json file 2 and so on. This should work for any amount of json files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "maximum element" in this context? I mean, what is the maximum value of a 'dog' or a 'cat'? By the way, aren't you missing some commas in your lists?

Comment: You could create a dictionary containing the list elements and their number and then use that to determine max and most common (obviously if there's a tie you'll have to determine how to break it)

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

example = [('dog'),('dog'),('cat'),('cat'),('fish'),('frog'),('frog')]
c = Counter(example)
print(c.most_common(3))
```

**Output:**

```
[('dog', 2), ('frog', 2), ('cat', 2)]
```

Comment: This wont work for my case as i am parsing in n amount of json files and extracting relevant information from certain fields and appending that information to lists( which i have successfully done that part). I then have to go and find the maximum within those lists but the amount of maximum elements in each list varies. This has to work for any amount of json files that are being parsed. So using most common(3) wont work as there could be 5 elements equal to the max in the list for json file 1 and 6 for the second json file and so on.

Comment: @cam95: The way your question is formulated, we have to guess at your intentions.That makes it a bit difficult to provide an answer that works. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [('dog'),('dog'),('cat'),('cat'),('fish'),('frog'),('frog')]
ca = Counter(a).most_common()
print([i[0] for i in ca if i[1] == max([i[1] for i in ca])])
# Should print : ['dog', 'cat', 'frog']
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended from @Rakesh:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

example = [('dog'),('dog'),('cat'),('cat'),('fish'),('frog'),('frog')]
c = Counter(example)

_c = defaultdict(list)
for field in c.most_common():
    _c[field[1]].append(field[0])

print(_c)
print(max(_c))
print(_c[max(_c)])
-----
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: ['dog', 'cat', 'frog'], 1: ['fish']})
2
['dog', 'cat', 'frog']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Could you maybe briefly explain what is happening at _c[field[1]].append(field[0]), that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @cam95 The value of field is `('dog', 2)`, so the field[1] is the count of 'dog' and the field[0] is the string `dog`.  `_c` is a defaultdict, defaultdict will create a object by its first argument when we set a not exist key for it.  The above code equals `_c={} try: _c[2].append('dog') except: _c[2]=['dog']`。